# Change orientation of a TikZ mindmap node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, mindmaps

[image: Turn node Shirts]

Here my MWE using code from the [Arrows](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/circular-arrows-text/) e [decorations.text](ftp://ftp.dante.de/ctan%3A/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ-fr.pdf) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=19cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,decorations.text}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\arrow{
  (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) arc (6.25:120:1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:0.9) [rounded corners=1] -- (130:1.1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:1.3) [sharp corners] -- (120:1.2) arc (120:5.25:1.2)
  [rounded corners=1] -- (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) -- cycle
}
\tikzset{
  ashadow/.style={opacity=.25, shadow xshift=0.07, shadow yshift=-0.07},
}
\def\arrows[#1]{
  \begin{scope}[scale=#1]
    \draw[left color=red, right color=red!60] \arrow;
  \end{scope}
}
\begin{document} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
\tikzset{every node/.style={text width=1cm,minimum size=1cm}}
 \node [concept, text=white,align=left,scale=0.5] at (0,0) 
      {people} 
child [concept color=red!50, grow=-90,level distance=70]
    {node [concept] {Shoes}
child [concept color=green!50,grow=-15,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {Shirts}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-75,level distance=75,rotate=-40]
    {node [concept] {Birds}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=155,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {cups}}
    }} ;
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-3.5cm,xshift=4.5cm]
        \draw node at (1,-6) [text width=3cm] {\small I do not want the arm that connects the nodes \\ shoes and shirts to be touched by the nodes birds or cups, \\ but I also do not want to change the angle formed between \\ birds and cups, I just want to rotate the node Shirts}; \draw [decorate,decoration={text along path,text={Turn Shirts}}]   (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) arc (6.25:120:1) [rounded corners=0.5] -- (120:0.9) [rounded corners=1] -- (130:1.1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:1.3) [sharp corners] -- (120:1.2) arc (120:5.25:1.2)
  [rounded corners=1] -- (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) -- cycle;
        \arrows[1]
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is my work that gave rise to my doubt. Note that one of the childs nodes touches one of the arms.

Without key `rotate=-20` and code below:

[image: Without key rotate=-20]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[paperwidth=45cm,paperheight=59cm,left=10cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{document} \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
        \tikzset{every node/.style={text width=1cm,minimum size=1cm},text=green}
        \node [concept] at (0,0) 
    {People}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-15,level distance=170]
        {node [concept] {Shoes}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-75,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-50,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-25,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {Not touch}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-100,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-125,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-150,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-175,level distance=75]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=142.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=197.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=222.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=247.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=272.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=297.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=322.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=350,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=17.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=42.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=67.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=117.5,level distance=105]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=185,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=210,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=235,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=260,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=285,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=310,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=335,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=130]
        {node [concept] {}}
    child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=155]
        {node [concept] {}}
        }
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Now with key `rotate=-20`, see:

[image: With key rotate=-20 in the node child "Shoes"]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=45cm,paperheight=59cm,left=10cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \tikzset{every node/.style={text width=1cm,minimum size=1cm},text=green}
    \node [concept] at (0,0) 
{People}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-15,level distance=170,rotate=-20]
    {node [concept] {Shoes}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-75,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-50,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-25,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {Not touch}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-100,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-125,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-150,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-175,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=142.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=197.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=222.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=247.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=272.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=297.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=322.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=350,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=17.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=42.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=67.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=117.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=185,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=210,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=235,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=260,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=285,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=310,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=335,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=155]
    {node [concept] {}}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Soon only the node child "Not touch" moves, remaining and breaking the symmetry with other sibling nodes.

Using the following examples of [polar axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251504/issue-plotting-polar-data-using-tikz) and on [background layer code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144402/positioning-a-tikz-scope-relative-to-another-tikz-scope), I did a check if using at at ([yshift = 19.3pt] -0: 0pt) on the following path {node [concept] at at ([yshift = 19.3pt] -0: 0pt) {Shoes} ... and get the following results as images below and their respective MWE below each image. Note that in the first original image the node "Not touch" is touching the "People" arm, in the second image this problem is solved using as an example the suggestion of @marmot, at ([yshift = 19.3pt] -0: 0pt) but it also causes "People"'s arm position change and I want to avoid it:

[image: Touch Yes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=22cm,left=-14cm,top=-10cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,mindmap,backgrounds,scopes}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    \begin{polaraxis}[on background layer,
    width=23cm,
        grid=both
    ]
\end{polaraxis}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={($(scope1)+(0cm,0)$)}]
    \tikzset{every node/.style={text width=1cm,minimum size=1cm},text=green}
    \node [concept] at (0,0) 
{People}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-15,level distance=170]
    {node [concept]{Shoes}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-75,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-50,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-25,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {Not touch}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-100,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-125,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-150,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-175,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=142.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=197.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=222.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=247.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=272.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=297.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=322.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=350,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=17.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=42.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=67.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=117.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=185,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=210,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=235,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=260,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=285,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=310,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=335,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=155]
    {node [concept] {}}
    }
;

    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Not Touch]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=22cm,left=-14cm,top=-10cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,mindmap,backgrounds,scopes}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=scope1]
    \begin{polaraxis}[on background layer,
    width=23cm,
        grid=both
    ]
\end{polaraxis}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={($(scope1)+(0cm,0)$)}]
    \tikzset{every node/.style={text width=1cm,minimum size=1cm},text=green}
    \node [concept] at (0,0) 
{People}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-15,level distance=170]
    {node [concept] at ([yshift=19.3pt]-0:0pt){Shoes}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-75,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-50,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-25,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {Not touch}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-100,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-125,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-150,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-175,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=142.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=197.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=222.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=247.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=272.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=297.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=322.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=350,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=17.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=42.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=67.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=117.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=185,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=210,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=235,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=260,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=285,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=310,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=335,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=155]
    {node [concept] {}}
    }
;

    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a `clockwise from=` key that allows you change how the nodes are connected. You might want to explore how that works.

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, I know the key clockwise from = but it does not have the desired effect, since I need to rotate (simultaneously and parallelly, or translate) the two childs of the Node Shirts, I already tried to use clockwise from = to cups, but this MWE is just a small example of another work of mine mindmap. This other mindmap of mine contains more than 20 childs and not space to use clockwise from =, because if using this key I will superimpose one of the childs.

Comment: I could adjust the grow = key of each node child, one after another, this is an alternative but would be a very manual work.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER** (for updated question). Just add an `yshift`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=45cm,paperheight=59cm,left=10cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \tikzset{every node/.style={text width=1cm,minimum size=1cm},text=green}
    \node [concept] at (0,0) 
{People}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-15,level distance=170,rotate=-20,yshift=17pt]
    {node [concept] {Shoes}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-75,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-50,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-25,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {Not touch}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-100,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-125,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-150,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-175,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=142.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=197.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=222.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=247.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=272.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=297.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=322.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=350,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=17.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=42.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=67.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=117.5,level distance=105]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=105,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=130,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=red!50,grow=155,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=185,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=210,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=235,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=260,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=285,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=310,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=335,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=5,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=30,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=55,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=80,level distance=130]
    {node [concept] {}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=92.5,level distance=155]
    {node [concept] {}}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ANSWER TO ORIGINAL QUESTION**: I think you want a separate node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperwidth=15cm,paperheight=19cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,decorations.text}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\arrow{
  (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) arc (6.25:120:1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:0.9) [rounded corners=1] -- (130:1.1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:1.3) [sharp corners] -- (120:1.2) arc (120:5.25:1.2)
  [rounded corners=1] -- (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) -- cycle
}
\tikzset{
  ashadow/.style={opacity=.25, shadow xshift=0.07, shadow yshift=-0.07},
}
\def\arrows[#1]{
  \begin{scope}[scale=#1]
    \draw[left color=red, right color=red!60] \arrow;
  \end{scope}
}
\begin{document} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
\tikzset{every node/.style={text width=1cm,minimum size=1cm}}
 \node [concept, text=white,align=left,scale=0.5] at (0,0) 
      {people} 
child [concept color=red!50, grow=-90,level distance=70]
     {node [concept] {Shoes}};
\node [concept,concept color=green!50, text=white,align=left,scale=0.5] 
at ([yshift=-70pt]-15:130pt) 
 {Shirts}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=-75,level distance=75,rotate=-40]
    {node [concept] {Birds}}
child [concept color=blue!50,grow=155,level distance=75]
    {node [concept] {cups}
    } ;
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-3.5cm,xshift=4.5cm]
        \draw node at (1,-6) [text width=3cm] {\small I do not want the arm that connects the nodes \\ shoes and shirts to be touched by the nodes birds or cups, \\ but I also do not want to change the angle formed between \\ birds and cups, I just want to rotate the node Shirts}; \draw [decorate,decoration={text along path,text={Turn Shirts}}]   (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) arc (6.25:120:1) [rounded corners=0.5] -- (120:0.9) [rounded corners=1] -- (130:1.1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:1.3) [sharp corners] -- (120:1.2) arc (120:5.25:1.2)
  [rounded corners=1] -- (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) -- cycle;
        \arrows[1]
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @marmot, this is the work that gave rise to my doubt, in it you can see that I hope to maintain the union of all nodes childs. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNGo9.png

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah Do you want to keep the connection and just to rotate the nodes such that they do not overlap?

Comment: Exactly @marmot , I want to keep the distance between all node childs exactly as they are.

Comment: How about adding `,rotate=-20` to the `cups` node?

Comment: I had already tried rotate, and result this is https://imgur.com/a/EhwiRUW. It's like your I wanted with a single key statement clockwise from = did a general rotation of all child nodes to the same direction and drives around the main node.

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah It is hard to answer the question since you apply the suggestions to another example. If you add `clockwise from=`, the precise location of that key matters.

Comment: I tried adding a new example in the initial question with key rotate=-20.

Comment: @DiegoBneiNoah You can just add a bit of an `yshift`. I updated my answer.